# remove the wrapping <div class="textwidget"> around the textwidget calling function

Tags: wordpress, widget

The problem is that when i call the textwidget code  wraps around it.I searched through the internet and got 2 solutions- firstly to remove the class from wp-includes/default-widgets.php, which requires changes in core files and is certainly not recommended.
Secondly using JQuery to remove the class.Its required method but i'm unable to implement it as detailed description cannot be found,as where to include the code..in function.php??or anywhere else...If anyone can provide the example or detailed description for it.....without the  removal my design of website becomes a mess....

Comment: I guess you will need to format your question properly to get proper attention!

Answer (score -2):

Define these fields in the functions.php

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Sidebar name',
        'id' => 'sidebar_name',
        'before_widget' => '', //Leave Blank
        'after_widget' => '', //Leave Blank
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="offscreen">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks...but the wrapping class is still there.my design of site is affected.

Comment: Does this help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54987/remove-div-class-textwidget-from-text-widget